# Lighttpd Virtual hosts

Tags: virtualhost, lighttpd

Ok guys, I'm in a mess.

Check my lighttpd.conf here, http://pastebin.com/m4c398259.

I've got no idea really, I've read as much up and tried as many tutorials as I possibly can. But this is above my skill level. Someone help me re-write my mess to accommodate my two domains I wish to host :)

Thanks a HUGE amount guys. Honestly.

Comment: So let me get this straight... you don't have an actual question? You just want us to rewrite your lighttpd config?

Comment: Don't expect others to do your homework...

Comment: Not really re-write, my question is obviously worded wrong, but I just am unsure as to where I am going wrong. The answer below actually is what I was looking for.

Comment: Then you should accept the answer to indicate that this question has been answered. :)

Comment: pastebin question is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the configuration, `mod_simple_vhost` is not enabled. Just enable that and you will be able to host as many domains/sub-domains as you want. It merely splits those up into individual directories.

You should refer to the lighttpd [wiki](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModSimpleVhost) for more configuration information.